# FATAL ERROR- When analyzing project

Tags: sonarqube, fatal-error

I got Fatal Error when analyzed a project in sonar. what i have to do for solving this issue.
Here is my log file data.

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Preparing cobertura:cobertura
[INFO] [dotnet:compile {execution: default-compile}]
[INFO] The project Atlas is not a visual studio project
[INFO] [cobertura:instrument {execution: default-instrument}]
[INFO] Not executing cobertura:instrument as the project is not a Java classpath
-capable package
[INFO] [dotnet:test {execution: default-test}]
[INFO] The project Atlas is not a visual studio project
[INFO] [cobertura:cobertura {execution: default-cli}]
[INFO] Not executing cobertura:report as the cobertura data file (D:\projects\At
las\target\cobertura\cobertura.ser) could not be found
[INFO] [14:49:17.078] Execute org.codehaus.mojo:cobertura-maven-plugin:2.4:cober
tura done: 7453 ms
[INFO] [14:49:17.078] Execute maven plugin cobertura-maven-plugin done: 7453 ms
[INFO] [14:49:17.078] Sensor CoverageSensor...
[INFO] [14:49:17.078] xml file path for coverityD:\projects\Atlas\target\site
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] FATAL ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Java heap space
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap spac
at org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl.createChunk(Unknown Source
)
at org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl.ensureCapacity(Unknown Sou
rce)
at org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl.createNode(Unknown Source)

    at org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl.createDeferredAttribute(Un
known Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl.setDeferredAttribute(Unkno
wn Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractDOMParser.startElement(Unknown Sour
ce)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElemen
t(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContent
Dispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Un
known Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:208)
    at org.sonar.plugins.cpp.coverage.CoverageConvertor.generateOutputFile(C
overageConvertor.java:62)
    at org.sonar.plugins.cpp.coverage.CoverageSensor.analyse(CoverageSensor.
java:97)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:6
4)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.Phases.execute(Phases.java:93)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ProjectModule.doStart(ProjectModule.java:13
9)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Module.start(Module.java:83)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchModule.analyze(BatchModule.java:115)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchModule.doStart(BatchModule.java:105)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Module.start(Module.java:83)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapModule.doStart(BootstrapModule.jav
a:111)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Module.start(Module.java:83)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.startBatch(Batch.java:73)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:60)
    at org.sonar.maven.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:150)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPlugi
nManager.java:490)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.Bootstraper.executeMojo(Bootstraper.java:98)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.Bootstraper.start(Bootstraper.java:79)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 11 minutes 32 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Dec 06 14:49:22 IST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 38M/63M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How about increasing the heap size?  Essentially set `MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx1024m` (or a higher value) and rerun.

Comment: where should i have to increase heap size?in which file?

Comment: @Renjith.R.  Environment variable